# Delphi: Simple hh:mm:ss Timer

Tags: delphi, timer

Does anybody have a short and effective code for hh:mm:ss timer (Timer1.Interval:=1000)? I can make one but I want something efficient.

Thanks!

My Code:

```
Var MyTime:TTime;

MyTime:=EncodeTime(0,0,0,0);

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
MyTime:=incsecond(Mytime,1);
form1.Label1.Caption:='Time: '+TimeToStr(MyTime);
end;
```

Comment: It is impossible to know what you want to do based solely on the information given in your question. You need to tell us what exactly you wish to accomplish. Do you want help converting a number of milliseconds to hours, minutes, and seconds, or do you want animate a digital clock counting down, or ... ?

Comment: just to show time (hh:mm:ss) in Label. "Converting a number of milliseconds to hours, minutes, and seconds," or without converting if it is possible to do.

Comment: Define efficient?  Minimal execution time? Minimal code? Minimal StackOverflow lookups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add A Var to keep track of when the timer started.

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    timerStart: TDateTime;
  public
    proceure StartTimer;
  end;
```

The procedure To start the Timer

```
proceure TForm1.StartTimer;
beign
 timerStart := now();
 timer1.interval = 1000;
 timer1.enabled := true;
end;
```

In the OnTimer Event

```
Label1.caption := formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss', timerStart - now()); //nn is for minutes.
```

This should show the correct time taken for any interval.
*i.e.* 5000 to show every 5 seconds, the time taken.

**Note:** With out testing, running the timer for longer than 24 hours might not show the correct time difference. For that *I think* that the datetime format string should be something like `dd hh:nn:ss` to show the days passed

Comment: +1 For using FormatDateTime, but -1 for trying to put a double in Tag. = 0

Comment: Fair Call, i forget sometimes that TdateTime is not a int.